# Question about gzip compression and compress effectiveness

Tags: node.js, websocket, base64, rsa, gzip

I'm using RSA encryption between a WebSocket server and a WebSocket client. This is fine from small messages with just small amounts of info. The problem I'm running into is there's one part of my program that needs a very large message, like 1 MB in size, to be sent to the server. this means I cannot Encrypt the whole message using RSA encryption. As there's a max number of bytes that can be encrypted with the public key. So I'm opting into splitting the message into chunks and sending multiple messages and remaking the message on the other size. This requires me to chuck the message. So I'm wondering if its move effective to **base64** the message before **gzipping** it. or should I base64 it after? As **gzipping** gives me a byte array, meaning I have to encode it anyway. Which path provides better performance?

Comment: base64-encoding before gzipping just wastes time and expands the message, even after it's gzipped.

Comment: Okay, thank you. much appreciate it.

Comment: Just use hybrid encryption: generate a random AES key, encrypt your data using the generated AES key and the encrypt the AES key using RSA.

Comment: yea this is what I did. it took too much time to rsa the chucks. which is prob why people don't do it.